# Should I run 2-wheeler at constant speed?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, energy-efficiency

I have been recommended not to run the two-wheeler (Suzuki Access) at a constant speed (I give a constant throttle in a way that I run essentially at a constant speed of about 40-45 kmph). In fact, I have been told to keep changing the acceleration (smoothly though) for lesser fuel consumption. I want to understand the technical reason behind this claim.

Comment: (1) What is a Suzuki Access? Is it a petrol engined motor bike? (2) Your post seems to mix up speed and acceleration. Can you edit your post to clarify exactly what you are asking?

Comment: I think he's more likely mixing up 'acceleration' and 'the position of the accelerator (throttle)'?

Comment: @Transistor Suzuki Access is a scooter running on petrol

Comment: @JonathanRSwift Thanks for pointing out. I realize that 'the position of the accelerator (throttle)' makes more sense than writing 'acceleration'.

Answer (score 1):

Your question doesn't make much sense.

- For a given set of conditions - selected gear, gradient, load, wind and road resistance - there is a required power to maintain constant speed.
- Since power is a function of throttle position and this increases with throttle rotation then there must be only one throttle position that generates that power.

[image]

The graph and topic is discussed further in https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/57888/why-does-higher-acceleration-minimize-a-cars-fuel-consumption.

Answer (score 0):

The optimum speed for obtaining maximum efficiency varies is not a constant with the load. That might be the reason for the advice.